# Clustered Managed Servers are not coming up - Weblogic 12.2.1.3

Tags: java-8, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have created a clustered domain using weblogic 12.2.1.3. The domain contains a Admin server, and 2 managedServer(under a cluster).

**Note :** ManagedServers are in different VM's

After installation i'm able to start admin and managedServer1, but managedServer2 is throwing the below exception.

**BEA-171529** -- Unable to download the initial replica of security data from the AdminServer. Verify that clock skew has not occurred between the servers in the domain. The underlying exception was java.io.IOException: Multiple failures to read VDE replica, network issues suspected
BEA-090403 -- Authentication for user weblogic denied.

**BEA-000386** -- Server subsystem failed. Reason: A MultiException has 4 exceptions.  They are:
1. weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication for user weblogic denied.
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.security.SecurityService
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.nodemanager.adminserver.NodeManagerMonitorService errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.nodemanager.adminserver.NodeManagerMonitorService

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: Check your timezones. If both Managed servers on different timezones then one managed servers will not start because of time zone issue.

Solution: Set the timezone to GMT in both managed servers using  -Duser.timezone=GMT

Case 2: If your server host machine is converted from windows to Linux, then you will face the connection problems between the servers.